# Dict and List Manipulation Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, set

I have two files one has key and other has both key and value. I have to match the key of file one and pull the corresponding value from file two. When all the key and value are in plain column format i can get the key and value to a new file very well. But I am not understanding how to get a result when the value is in set/array type.

Input one in column format:

```
5216 3911 2 761.00 
2503 1417 13 102866.00
5570 50 2 3718.00 
5391 1534 3 11958.00 
5015 4078 1 817.00 
3430 299 1 5119.00 
4504 3369 2 3218.00  
4069 4020 2 17854.00 
5164 4163 1 107.00 
3589 3026 1 7363.00
```

Input two in column format. They are key as pair i.e. `col[0]` and `col[1]` both are key as pairs

```
5391 1534 
5015 4078 
3430 299 
4504 3369
```

Output for the above input case, which is right for me

```
5391 1534 3 11958.00 
5015 4078 1 817.00 
3430 299 1 5119.00 
4504 3369 2 3218.00
```

Program

```
from collections import defaultdict

edges = {}
with open('Input_1.txt', 'r') as edge_data:    
    for row in edge_data:
        col = row.strip().split()
        edges[col[0], col[1]] = col[2], col[3]
#Then to do the queries, read through the first file and print out the matches:
with open('Input_2', 'r') as classified_data:
    with open ('Output', 'w') as outfile:    
    for row in classified_data:
            a,b = row.strip().split()
        c = edges.get((a,b), edges.get((b,a)))

        #print a,b, edges.get((a,b), edges.get((b,a)))
        #print a,b,c        
        outfile.write("%s %s %s\n" % (a,b,c))
```

The above program works great for the above given input types. But I have no clue how to get the operations for the below given inputs.

I understand I am supposed to change this statement from the above program but I am not getting any clue what should that be changed to ?

```
edges[col[0], col[1]] = col[2], col[3]
```

New Input one

```
('3350', '2542') [6089.0, 4315.0] 
('2655', '1411') [559.0, 1220.0, 166.0, 256.0, 146.0, 528.0, 1902.0, 880.0, 2317.0, 2868.0] 
('4212', '1613') [150.0, 14184.0, 4249.0, 1250.0, 10138.0, 4281.0, 2846.0, 2205.0, 1651.0, 335.0, 5233.0, 149.0, 6816.0] 
('4750', '2247') [3089.0] 
('5305', '3341') [13122.0]
```

New Input two They are key as pair i.e. `col[0]` and `col[1]` both are key as pairs

```
3350 2542
4750 2247
5305 3341
```

Expected output is

```
3350 2542 6089.0
3350 2542 4315.0
4750 2247 3089.0
5305 3341 13122.0
```

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Included few more details.

Comment: A request to everyone if you don't understand or if you don't want to answer then please don't bother but atleast don't put wrong/close flags. It might not be important for you but the solution to this is really important for me.

Comment: If someone feels its unclear what you are asking, they are free to flag your question. It will go into the review queue and more experienced users of the community will decide whether or not the flag was just. Whether or not the content of the question is of importance to anyone is a different matter.
Bottom line: dont worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought @three_pineapples's `eval` manner is quite good and brilliant,

Here is an alternative one which only manipulate string:

```
edges = {}
with open("Input_1.txt", "r") as edge_data:
    for row in edge_data:
        k, v = row.strip().split(")") # split as key, value
        k = " ".join(i.strip("'") for i in k.strip("(").split(", ")) # clean unwanted symbol and merge together
        v = v.strip(" []").split(", ") # get list value
        edges[k] = v

with open("Input_2", "r") as classified_data:
    for row in classified_data:
        k = row.strip();
        for v in edges.get(k, []):
            print k, v
```

Comment: This is Great.. Exactly what I have been struggling for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching

```
import re
rec = re.compile(r"\('(\d+)',\s*'(\d+)'\)\s*\[(.*)\]")
matches = rec.match("('3350', '2542') [6089.0, 4315.0]")
print matches.groups()
print int(matches.group(1))
print int(matches.group(2))
print map(float, matches.group(3).split(','))
```

The output is

```
('3350', '2542', '6089.0, 4315.0')
3350
2542
[6089.0, 4315.0]
```

To save the data

```
a = int(matches.group(1))
b = int(matches.group(2))
data = map(float, matches.group(3).split(','))
edges[a,b] = data
```

To get data and print the output

```
c = edges.get((a,b), edges.get((b,a)))
for value in c:
   print "%s %s %s\n" % (a,b, value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but `3350', '2542'` as pair is the key and `6089.0` is one value of the pair and `4315.0` is the second value of the same pair.

Comment: Yup, like in your older code you used `col[0],col[1]` as tuple use `group(1) , group(2)` as tuple :D (I have updated answer, value is a list)

Comment: Oh just iterate over the mapped value list. When you find a tuple in your edges, iterate over all values and print

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting the string on a different caharacter, say `')'`

So you would do something like:

```
with open('Input_1.txt', 'r') as edge_data:    
    for row in edge_data:
        col = row.strip().split(')')
```

You then want to convert the string representation of a tuple and a list, into something you can work with. You can do this by using `eval()`

```
        key = eval(col[0]+')') # note I add the bracket back in that we split on
        value = eval(col[1])
        edges[key] = value
```

You now have a dictionary `edges` with keys that match the tuple in file one and values that contain the associated lists

When you read in file 2, you will need to add another loop that iterates over the entries in the list. For example, something like

```
for c in edges[(a,b)]:
    outfile.write("%s %s %s\n" % (a,b,c))
```

This will allow you to write a line to your output file for each entry in the list you read in from the first file.

Comment: @SitzBlogz What exactly did you find confusing? I deliberately didn't spoon feed you an answer you could copy/paste so that you might learn something.